# Power BI - How to combine this year's & last year's results into a single measure?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two measures. One calculates sales from the year selected in a slicer:

```
Sales_this_year =
VAR V_year = SELECTEDVALUE(my_table[YEAR])
RETURN
CALCULATE(SUM(my_table[SALES]),
my_table[YEAR] = V_year)
```

The other calculates sales from the previous year; the only change to the DAX is subtracting 1 from the year selected in the slicer:

```
Sales_last_year =
VAR V_year = SELECTEDVALUE(my_table[YEAR])-1
RETURN
CALCULATE(SUM(my_table[SALES]),
my_table[YEAR] = V_year)
```

The two measures are then displayed on my report in separate cards.

Having two separate measures that are so similar seems inefficient. Is it possible to create a single measure like this and display it in both cards, but with something in place to filter each card to the required year based on what's selected in the slicer?

```
Sales = SUM(my_table[SALES])
```

Comment: No. They mean different things and how would you write a growth measure without both of them? (Well unless you recreated one or both inside your measure calculation)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum your sales based on the last 2 years you can use:

```
Sales_last_2_Years = 
CALCULATE(SUM(my_table[SALES]), DATESINPERIOD(my_table[DATE], MAX(my_table[DATE]), -2, YEAR))
```

This will  sum the sales for the specified period (last 2 years)